# iSeries: Error fetching SQL resultset from an RPG program calling a stored procedure on another iSeries system

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Short description: 
after a call to an SQL procedure stored in a different iSeries I'm trying to access the resultset using associated cursor but fetch statement results in MCH3601 "POINTER NOT SET FOR LOCATION REFERENCED" error.

Details:
an SQLRPGLE program executes the following D and C specifications to call an SQL stored procedure which runs on a different iSeries and return a single row with a single field :

```
** Locator definition
D OUTPIK          S                   SQLTYPE(RESULT_SET_LOCATOR)    
** Resultset definition as the thirdy-part developer told us it is
D DSPIK           DS                  OCCURS(1)         
D  FLPIK                         1A                     

// Connecting to a second iSeries
EXEC SQL 
  CONNECT TO :wrkDBR  USER :wrkUSER USING :wrkPWD;

// Calling stored procedure
EXEC SQL 
  CALL LOGF10OPIN/DEDALO_SIRE_POSTOPICKING (:CAZI_S, :CEDI_S, :CART_S);

// Associating SQL locator to SP resultset
EXEC SQL 
  ASSOCIATE RESULT SET LOCATORS (:OUTPIK) 
    WITH PROCEDURE LOGF10OPIN/DEDALO_SIRE_POSTOPICKING;

// Allocating result set to a cursor
EXEC SQL 
  ALLOCATE CPI CURSOR FOR RESULT SET :OUTPIK;

// Fetching resul set into a variable defined as CHAR(1) 
EXEC SQL 
  fetch CPI into :DSPIK;

// Closing cursor
EXEC SQL 
  CLOSE CPI;

// Disconnecting
EXEC SQL 
  DISCONNECT :wrkDBR;
```

Assuming each SQL statement execution is checked through SQLCA variables, what happens is that fetch statement results in "MCH3601 - POINTER NOT SET FOR LOCATION REFERENCED" as if it wasn't able to access memory location to result set.

Further investigation:
the following statement run from an SQL client (IBM or DBeaver) on the same system where the SP is stored, returns the right value (for example 'N')

```
CALL LOGF10OPIN.DEDALO_SIRE_POSTOPICKING ('A01', '00M1', '0000123');
```

but when I do the same call with the following statements from iSeries I need to call the SP from, the result is unexpected

```
CONNECT TO B0050C2B  USER RETAIL USING 'xxx';
CALL LOGF10OPIN.DEDALO_SIRE_POSTOPICKING ('A01', '00M1', '0000123');
DISCONNECT B0050C2B;
```

the answer I see on the FTP client is value 'D5' which is EBCDIC hexadecimal value for 'N'!

Final considerations:

- different SQL clients from which the call is issued that include the connection to the second iSeries return different values: EBCDIC hexadecimal value for expected value (IBM SQL client) or even a lower 'a' (DBeaver)

- I can't access the iSeries that holds and runs the SP so I can't check whether the two systems are at the same PTF level or any other configuration parameter

Does this issue sound familiar to any of you?

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: A couple comments:  an SQLDA is not used here since this is all static SQL. Maybe you mean t SQLCA? And, since you are at v7.1 or later, there is no point in propagating old v4.2 syntax. Just use free format. It is much easier to read.

Comment: Nulls you need two vars on fetch one for the null indicator one for the data.  I've never seen some of this code before associate to procedure.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Yes, you're right: it's SQLCA, I corrected it. Next time I will use free format when writing code here, but at work we are asked to use fixed format.

Comment: @danny117 I'm using code as it is written in IBM official documentation; I found same kind of implementation in internet and I've already use it successfully; what would you do instead? What do you mean by "need two vars on fetch"?

Comment: If you have a possibility of null fields in your result set, you can use something like `FETCH CUR INTO :VAR:INDVAR` where INDVAR is a numeric field that will be < 0 if VAR is null. This is not necessary though, and it causes a different error if VAR is null and you have no INDVAR defined.

Comment: Another thought, though I don't know why it would make any difference here. You can use arrays rather than multi-occurrence data structures. Replace the `OCCURS` with a `DIM`. Though in this case just a plain data structure will do as well. You don't show all the code, but maybe you have an `OCCUR` op code somewhere in the unshown code that points outside the data-structure. Also, make sure you test the `SQLCODE` after your call to make sure that the stored procedure has returned a result set. the `SQLCODE` should be `+466` if a result set was returned.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy I wab able to replicate the same error with another SP which I have complete access of in other systems: if the SP runs on the same system it gives back all results, if it runs after connected to another system it results in the same error. Even this time I'm using OCCUR because this is the case, anyway the first procedure always returns  at least one row because it's a flag Y or N.

Comment: I agree with you that the result set could be an array instead of a multi-occurence DS, but it already works without problem when called via web application, though I don't know how web application reaches the IBM system.

Comment: The web application may be calling the Stored Procedure via ODBC rather than RPG. What release of the OS are you using both local and remote?

Comment: V7R2 on both system; the exception arises even on another couple of systems so I'm figuring out that some specifications in my code are wrong. Probably or fetch statement or cursor definition are not right.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue needs a PTF from IBM to be solved on V7R1 and V7R2.